# TSQL Case in where statement if parameter is null

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a SP that gives me a lot of hard times.

The sp gets a two parameters @madeByUserId and @reportedByUserId.
I want to have something like:

```
 select * from table
  where MadeByUserId = @madeByUserId (if(@reportedByUserID != null) and ReportedByUserID = @reportedByUserID)
```

Basically I want to make a case in the where clause to include another filter condition based of the null/not null state of the @reportedByUserId

Is that possible?

Thanks a lot, 
Radu

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try:

```
 select * from table
 where MadeByUserId = @madeByUserId 
 AND (@reportedByUserID IS null OR ReportedByUserID = @reportedByUserID)
```

Comment: Or in a more concise way:
`where MadeByUserId = @madeByUserId 
 AND ReportedByUserID = isnull(@reportedByUserID, ReportedByUserID)`

Answer (score 10):

You could use `COALESCE`.

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    Table
WHERE   MadeByUserId = @madeByUserId 
        AND ReportedByUserID = COALESCE(@reportedByUserID, ReportedByUserID)
```

This translates to

```
 if @reportedByUserID is `NOT NULL` then 
   compare ReportedByUserID with @reportedByUserID
 else
   compare ReportedByUserID with ReportedByUserID
```

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258244(SQL.80).aspx)

> COALESCE
>
> Returns the first nonnull expression
>   among its arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Add an if statement

IF (@reportedByUserId IS NOT NULL)

SELECT * 
FROM  table t
WHERE t.MadeByUserId = madeByUserId etc

Answer (score 0):

I think this will give you what you're after.

```
IF (@reportedByUser IS NULL)
    select * from table 
    where MadeByUserId = @madeByUserId
ELSE
    select * from table 
    where MadeByUserId = @madeByUserId and ReportedByUserID = @reportedByUserID)
```