# SQL Server - Using CASE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a SELECT statement with a WHERE clause that I want to dynamically change depending if a parameter is supplied or not.

I can't seem to understand how to use CASE statement in a WHERE clause but this is how I want it to look like using an IF statement.

```
DECLARE @Gender NVARCHAR(100) = NULL --this is an INPUT parameter and may or may not be NULL
DECLARE @Status NVARCHAR(100) = NULL --this is an INPUT parameter and may or may not be NULL

    SELECT Name
    FROM Person
    WHERE 
        -- first WHERE clause
        IF @Gender IS NULL
           BEGIN
                Gender IS NULL
           END
        ELSE
           BEGIN
                Gender = @Gender
           END
    AND
        -- second WHERE clause
        IF @Status IS NULL
           BEGIN
                Status IS NULL
           END
        ELSE
           BEGIN
                Status LIKE '%' + @Status + '%'
           END
```

Is it possible to transform this code into a `CASE` statement?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TSQL Case in where statement if parameter is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4385389/tsql-case-in-where-statement-if-parameter-is-null)

Comment: The solution link you provided unfortunately doesn't work if Gender IS NULL or Status IS NULL.

Comment: So far you have rejected all suggestions... but there is nothing in the question to test any solution with (sample data)...  and you have not provided the test cases either (expected results for parameter combinations).

Answer (score 2):

I think you want:

```
select p.name
from person p
where ( (@gender is null and gender is null) or gender = @gender) and
      ( (@status is null and status is null) or status = @status);
```

Note that this does "null-matching".  Often, people want to use `NULL` to select *all* records, not just the `NULL` ones.  If that is what you intend, then:

```
select p.name
from person p
where ( @gender is null or gender = @gender) and
      ( @status is null  or status = @status);
```

In either situation, `case` is not needed in the `where`.  As a general rule, don't use `case` in `where` -- unless you really need it to control the order of evaluation of expressions.

Comment: Since general rules are somewhat like best practices, as an alternative to this, can I have two different Stored Procedures that do the SELECT with different WHERE? And then have a main SP that just calls either of the two SELECT SPs depending if Gender or Status is null or not null? Or is using an SP to call another SP bad practice?

Comment: @thecodeexplorer There is no need for multiple SPs. You can have a single SP and use `if`/`then` logic to choose the appropriate `select` statement to execute. For another approach you may (or may not) want to read about [Dynamic Search Conditions in T-SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Gender NVARCHAR(100) = NULL --this is an INPUT parameter and may or may not be NULL
DECLARE @Status NVARCHAR(100) = NULL --this is an INPUT parameter and may or may not be NULL

SELECT Name
FROM Person
WHERE CASE WHEN @Gender IS NULL THEN 1
           WHEN @Gender = ISNULL(Gender, '') THEN 1
           ELSE 0
      END = 1
  AND CASE WHEN @Status IS NULL THEN 1
           WHEN ISNULL(Status, '') LIKE '%' + @Status + '%' THEN 1
           ELSE 0
      END = 1
```

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't work if Gender IS NULL or Status IS NULL

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
SELECT Name
FROM Person
WHERE Gender = COALESCE(@gender, Gender)
AND (@Status is null or Status like '%' + @status + '%')
```

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't work if Gender IS NULL or Status IS NULL